# Laravel @section @yield blade template not showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to seperate my menu from the `app.blade.php`. Why is the following not working?

`views/layouts/app.blade.php`:

```
<body>
@yield('menu')
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>
</body>
```

`views/layouts/menu.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('menu')
// Menu is here
@endsection
```

Comment: Try to use @include(layouts.menu) in app.blade.php

Comment: try to use @include('menu') in app.blade.php

Comment: @404BrainNotFound I tried your method (I did add `' '` around the `layouts.menu`. I got an error telling me the page is not working. (http500 error)

Comment: @KamleshGupta Upon using this solution I get `View [menu] not found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app.blade.php should be look like this

locate : views/layouts/app.blade.php

```
<body>
   @include('layouts.menu')
   <div class="container">
     @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

and your menu.blade.php

locate : views/layouts/menu.blade.php

```
// Menu's here
```

Comment: Thank you. I still had the section & extend in my `menu.blade.php` Removed these and now it works! Thanks :) Accepted

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to `yield` the menu section but `include` it. As you can read from the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views):

> Blade's @include directive allows you to include a Blade view from within another view. All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view:

```
<div>
  @include('shared.errors')

  <form>
  <!-- Form Contents -->
  </form>
</div>
```

So your `layouts/app.blade.php` file should look like this:

```
<body>
  @include('layouts.menu')

  <div class="container">
    @yield('content')
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this but I get the following error now `View [menu] not found.`

Comment: my bad... it's `include('layouts.menu')`, it depends on where you've saved your view. For example `views/frontend/form/checkout` will be included as `include('frontend.form.checkout)`